# to delete 14 row by 1 click

Tags: php, sql

I want make a delete when user click delete (example id=1) then it will delete all information from id=1 until id=14.

How ya?

I must get the id from the user first then it will delete for previous 14 row after the id.

Comment: Where is your code for your current attempt? What errors are you experiencing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have a hyperlink for delete action.

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>">
Delete Record
</a>
```

Here it appends record ID in url and it looks like `delete.php?id=15`

Now you want to delete previous 14 records.

```
$currentId = $_GET['id'];//got from URL
$nextLimit = $currentId - 14; //in case of next 14 you need to add
```

Your SQL Query should be:

```
$query = "delete from table
          where id between '$currentId' and '$nextLimit'";
```

and execute the query.

Comment: `GET` requests should *never* be used for anything that modifies data, the HTTP spec defines this. Doing things like this you're leaving yourself open to a web crawler or browser prefetch unintentionally wiping out all data from your site just by visiting links they find.